# How to force enable flash on Chrome 70 web driver? Not Chrome 62

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I'm facing an issue with enabling flash on Chrome 70 using selenium web driver. Every time I run a scenario it fails as the Install Flash comes up and it's waiting to be enabled.

```
I've done the below:
A) Coding:
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
                option.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                option.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
                Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
                // Enable Flash
                prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
                prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
                prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", NeonUtils.getConfigValue("url"));


B) Forcing flash to be enabled on Chrome Web driver, by following below steps:
   1. Input this URL in Chrome: chrome://flags/
   2. On search inbox, search for: ephemeral flash and disable it


Still it re-set the flash enablement next time I run the next scenario.
```

Comment: How about using a specific chrome profile for automation for which you manually enabled flash?

Comment: Ok, here's the fix to my problem - one more arguments was missing as below:
                option.addArguments("--disable-infobars", "--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission");